# How do I plot the position of a body in orbit using polar coordinates in python

Tags: python, position, ellipse, polar-coordinates, orbital-mechanics

Trying to plot the position of body in elliptical motion by solving Kepler's laws. I have a function for r (distance between focal point and body) and Theta (Angle between line connecting focal and body and horizontal) and when plotting (r, Theta) using plt.polar(r, Th) I get a messy plot [plt.polar(r, Th)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNJTh.png)(shown below)[plt.polar(r, Th)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ValKv.png) and plotting plt.polar(Th, r)[plt.polar(Th, r)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jLjD.png)[plt.polar(Th, r)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jLjD.png) gives me an almost correct looking ellipse but when I change the eccentricity it gives a non-ellipse shape. Any ideas of how I can plot the position?[plt.polar(r, Th)]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't see a plot or image. The documentation for `plt.polar()` is particularly poor because it doesn't explain what the values you are passing in should be. I would suggest using Matplotlib's object oriented API such as in this example https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_demo.html.

Note that the angle values need to be in radians, not degrees.